# Did the Raspberry Pi 5 drop hardware encoding support?

Tags: hardware, video, pi-5

Does the upcoming [Raspberry Pi 5](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-5/) have any hardware acceleration for video encoding? The [technical specifications](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-5/#specification) only list HEVC decoding, but there's no mention of hardware encoders. The reviews I've watched and read don't mention the Pi dropping hardware encoding either. Did they forget about it or does the Pi 5 truly lack hardware accelerated video encoding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Pi5 has no hardware support for video encoding.

See https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2139082#p2139126